# What is causing "warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression"?

Tags: c, macros, enums

I have an enum, and a macro definition and a method that all use the enum. I can't get it to compile. Consider the following pieces of code.

```
typedef enum fruits_t
{
    APPLE,
    ORANGE,
    BANANA
} fruits_t;

#define KEY_TO_VALUE(x) ((x == APPLE) ? 0 :  \
                         (x == ORANGE) ? 1 :  \
                         (x == BANANA) ? 2 : \
                         "Undefined")

static void foo(char fruit) {
    if (fruit == KEY_TO_VALUE(APPLE)) {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

This compiles, but I get the following warnings.

`warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression`

`warning: comparison between pointer and integer`

Why? I am very new to C, so if you could explain things that may seem obvious to an experienced C developer, I'd appreciate it. Most of my programming knowledge is Java based.

Comment: The problem is that "Undefined" can't be compared to a char. It is a string literal, so it is evaluated as a pointer.

Comment: As Nick said, You must declare your function this way: `static void foo( char * fruit)`

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto: That's an assumption. It's more likely that the parameter should be of type `int` (and the `"Undefined"` result should be changed to some `int` value, probably a constant).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The compiler is trying to figure out the type of each expression in the program.

An expression such as `x > 0 ? 5 : "no"` makes the compiler scratch its head. If x is greater than zero, the type is `int`, but if it isn't then the type is `const char *`. This is a problem, because there is no automatic conversion from pointer to `int` (and vice versa). So the compiler warns about it.

The solution is to make sure that no matter what the value of `fruit` is, the value of `KEY_TO_VALUE` has a single type. For example, instead of "Undefined" (which is of type `const char *`, because it is a literal string), you can use a special value such as -1.

Also, note that `APPLE` is a constant with the value 0, `ORANGE` is a constant with the value 1 and `BANANA` is a constant with the value 2 (this is how `enum` works). So you don't need `KEY_TO_VALUE`, as the constants already have the desired values. You can simply compare `fruit` to `APPLE` directly:

```
if (fruit == APPLE) { ... }
```

Comment: I know what you're talking about with your saying that the constants have my desired values. Its actually different than that in practice, I simplified it for this post.

Answer (score 4):

In C language the `?:` operator imposes the following requirements on its second and third operands

> One of the following shall hold for the second and third operands:
>
> - both operands have arithmetic type;
> - both operands have the same structure or union type;
> - both operands have void type;
> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
> - one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant; or
> - one operand is a pointer to an object or incomplete type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void.

In your code you are mixing arithmetic type and pointer type (string literal decays to `char *` type) as second and third operand of `?:`. This is not allowed.

Speaking informally, how did you even come up with that idea? What would be the type of something like `x == BANANA ? 2 : "Undefined"`? `int`? `char *`? Something else?

Note that mixing a pointer value and a constant `0` is allowed, i.e. expression `x == APPLE ? 0 : "Undefined"` would actually compile without any problems. However, the `0` would be interpreted as a *null pointer constant*, the whole expression would have pointer type (`char *`) and evaluate to a null pointer when `x == APPLE` is true. This is probably not what you intended.