# Calling a function by pointer chosen by ternary conditional

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers, ternary-operator

I have a function which reads data from file and another function that writes data into file. These functions are similar and differ only in the function being called, `fread` and `fwrite` respectively. So I want to unite them. However, I don't want to write something like `if (read) fread(args); else fwrite(same args);`.

So at first I tried this:

```
enum { F_READ, F_WRITE };
void rwFile(uint8_t rw, char *name);
...
rwFile(F_READ, name);
...
void rwFile(uint8_t rw, char *name)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(name, (rw == F_READ ? "rb" : "wb"));
    (rw == F_READ ? &fread : &fwrite) (&size, sizeof(size), 1, file);
    for (int i = 0; i < size.Y; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size.X; j++)
            (rw == F_READ ? fread : fwrite ) (data[i] + j*2, 2, 1, file);
    fclose(file);
    file = NULL;
}
```

Then I get:

```
main.c: In function ‘rwFile’:
main.c:199:26: warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression
  (rw == F_READ ? &fread : &fwrite) (&size, sizeof(size), 1, file);
                         ^
main.c:199:26: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
  (rw == F_READ ? &fread : &fwrite) (&size, sizeof(size), 1, file);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
main.c:202:27: warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression
    (rw == F_READ ? fread : fwrite ) (data[i] + j*2, 2, 1, file);
                          ^
main.c:202:27: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
    (rw == F_READ ? fread : fwrite ) (data[i] + j*2, 2, 1, file);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

Ok, let's try another variant:

```
typedef size_t (*rwFunc_t)(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *stream);
void rwFile(rwFunc_t rwFunc, char *name);
...
rwFile(fread, name);
...
void rwFile(rwFunc_t rwFunc, char *name)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(name, (rwFunc == fread ? "rb" : "wb"));
    (*rwFunc) (&size, sizeof(size), 1, file);
    for (int i = 0; i < size.Y; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size.X; j++)
            (*rwFunc) (data[i] + j*2, 2, 1, file);
    fclose(file);
    file = NULL;
}
```

And this works. However, I get some warnings from gcc:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:58:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘rwFile’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   rwFile(fread, argv[1]);
          ^~~~~
main.c:18:6: note: expected ‘rwFunc_t {aka long unsigned int (*)(const void *, long unsigned int,  long unsigned int,  struct _IO_FILE *)}’ but argument is of type ‘size_t (*)(void * restrict,  size_t,  size_t,  FILE * restrict) {aka long unsigned int (*)(void * restrict,  long unsigned int,  long unsigned int,  struct _IO_FILE * restrict)}’
 void rwFile(rwFunc_t rwFunc, char *name);
      ^~~~~~
main.c: In function ‘rwFile’:
main.c:198:35: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
  FILE *file = fopen(name, (rwFunc == fread ? "rb" : "wb"));
                                   ^~
```

This is because `fread` and `fwrite` have a bit different args:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

So, can it be solved in a nice way?

Comment: No "nice" way. Do it the `if`, `else` way. It's readable and clean.

Comment: The only other option would be to write wrapper functions for `fread` and `fwrite` that have compatible signatures (basically just a wrapper for fwrite would be enough). But still it seems to me like asking for trouble.

Comment: Nobody wants to types `the_same_arguments` twice. That's where good text editors come in. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is causing "warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318336/what-is-causing-warning-pointer-integer-type-mismatch-in-conditional-expressio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types of [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) and
[`fwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html) are different:

```
size_t fread(void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems, FILE *restrict stream);

size_t fwrite(const void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems, FILE *restrict stream);
```

Note that `const` on the first argument to `fwrite` that's missing in `fread`.

You'll have to overcome that difference.  Maybe it would be cleaner to pass the I/O function pointer to your function, but you probably still need to use:

```
size_t fwrite_alt(void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems, FILE *restrict stream)
{
    return fwrite(ptr, size, nitems, stream);
}
```

The interface of `fwrite_alt()` exactly matches that of `fread()`.

Incidentally, note that if you need to generate error messages, you probably need more information about which function was used — and what words to use in the error messages (and that's before you worry about I18N/L10N — internationalization and localization).  You should also be checking the return value from the read or write function — but there are different implications for short reads vs short writes, which also complicates error handling and reporting.  I'm not sure you're going to want to use this in the long term.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional operator has the following restriction (6.5.15 Conditional operator)

> 3 One of the following shall hold for the second and third operands:
>
> — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
>   compatible types;

The functions `fread` and `fwrite` have the following declarations

```
size_t fread(void * restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE * restrict stream);
size_t fwrite(const void * restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE * restrict stream);
```

As it is seen their declarations differ relative to the first parameters. These parameters have incompatible types because they are not identically qualified. As result the functions are also incompatible and may not be used in the conditional operator.